# Strip characters from JSON http response in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to work with a JSON response that is encapsulated with `()` like so:

```
({
  "status": "ok",
  "messages": {
    "generalMessages": [],
    "recordMessages": []
  },
  "foundRows": 2029
})
```

And I get the following error:

> Unexpected token ( in JSON at position 0

This prevents me from doing things like `.map(response => response.json().status);` because it isn't valid JSON.

**What I have tried:** In Angular 1.5, I solved this with the following:

```
(angular.fromJson(response.data.substr(1, response.data.length - 2), true))
```

But, to do that in Angular 2, it seems that I have to convert it to text and then back to JSON and that completely mangles the format.

**My Question:**
How can I strip the `()` on my end and work with the new result as JSON?

Comment: yes. because it is not a valid json data. Json allows only `[ ]` and `{ }`

Comment: I understand that. But I don't control what the server sends back. So how can I strip those characters on my end to allow me to work with it as JSON?

Comment: This is a bad practice. Work either with json objects or xml objects and not with strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `.text()` method from [`Response`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Response-class.html) and then use a plain `JSON.parse`

```js
.map(
  response => JSON.parse(
    response.text().substring(1, response.text().length - 2
  )['status']
)
```

I suppose you could (and probably should) expand on that to make sure the response is "text" and that it is the malformed kind that you demonstrate.

But the point is that if you were just manipulating the text response before, then there is nothing to stop you doing that now.

Comment: @GraysonKent I think you meant to say `text()` there. Which is interesting considering the documentation cites all that is supposed to be doing is calling `.toString()`.

Answer (score -1):

What about data.slice(1,data.length-1).toJSON()

On iPad, so syntax might not be quite right.

Comment: It's still a "string" until parsed, and not an "array". Also no such thing as `.toJSON()` on an array, or string.

Comment: Strings can be sliced [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and yes, my error - toJson is on a date obj